# PouchDB alldocs() vs bulkget()

Tags: pouchdb

I'm wanting to get a simple array of the latest revision of data, but unsure if I should use [`allDocs()`](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_fetch) or [`bulkGet()`](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#bulk_get), as they seem very similar.

From what I understand, `bulkGet()` doesn't have sorting, while `allDocs()` doesn't have revision handling; other than that they seem to provide the same outcome.

I'm interested in which has the better performance.

Answer (score 1):

`allDocs({include_docs: true})` is simple, probably faster and always fetches the newest revisions by default.

`bulkGet` is undocumented and only used internally for replication.

Comment: That seems to have changed, as `bulkGet` is now documented: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#bulk_get